# mithril: Why XHR request never occurs from immediately invoked function expression?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, express, iife

I have two implementations of a table, one of them can fetch via xhr from a local api server, the other one can't. Why does this happen?

The difference between them is that one is implemented as an immediately invoked function, the other one returns an object. Both expose the view function needed by mithril plus an oninit function where the request is done.

I've set up a [mmwe](https://github.com/azaroma/mithril-iife-issue/).

Comment: Nobody is going to go and rifle through your repo to try and find what part of it actually has something to do with this question. You need to include an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _in the body of the question_ when you ask a question here.

Comment: @JLRishe Cloning is easier than copy paste, i think. I included a minimal server and a minimal version of the involved components, what are you talking about? Where does it say *in the body of the question*? It says provide: 
git clone REPO && cd REPO && node server.js && **open browser**

Comment: What says to provide git clone REPO, etc.? Certainly not the page I linked to. No, it is well established that to ask a question about code, you should include the relevant code (not your entire program) in the body of the question. [Here is a meta thread about that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260453/should-using-whateverfiddle-com-as-part-of-the-question-be-discouraged). You just linked us to a repo consisting of 8 code files and didn't even tell us which file contains the code you're talking about or where that code is within the files.

Comment: To reiterate: You should not expect people to dig through your code to decipher what you're talking about, and you should include the relevant part of your code in your question, not in an offsite resource. Providing a fiddle or git repo is nice, but that is _secondary_ to providing all the needed details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the answer:

Since in the the return whole object syntax it is imperative to do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    oninit: model.load,
    view: function(){
        return /*...*/
    }
}
```

Apparently in revealing module form you have to do this:

```
var module = (function(){
    var oninit = function() {
        model.load()
    }
    var view = function() {
        return /*...*/
    }

    return { view: view, oninit: oninit }
}())

module.exports = module
```

This works for the moment but I will test further.